# Dapper not updating a bit column in a record

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dapper

I am using Dapper to run a stored procedure to update a record. As it is, the procedure will select the column from the record and try set it to a variable only if the variable is null (that is, because for other cases with more update-able columns we want to support partial updates of the record in the same stored procedure).

I keep trying to run a test to verify it works as expect, but it doesn't. It seems that the actual behavior is to entirely ignore the parameters I am passing to Dapper's method and update the record with whatever the value was previously (making it redundant).

Here is the code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MetaTokens_Update]
    @Id BIGINT,
    @IsRevoked BIT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        @IsRevoked = ISNULL(@IsRevoked, [IsRevoked])
    FROM [dbo].[MetaTokens] 
    WHERE [Id] = @Id;

    UPDATE [dbo].[MetaTokens] 
    SET 
        [IsRevoked] = @IsRevoked
    WHERE [Id] = @Id;

END
```

```cs
    public async Task UpdateMetaTokenAsync(MetaTokenRow row)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@Id", row.TokenTypeKey);
        parameters.Add("@IsRevoked", row.IsRevoked);
        await Connection.ExecuteAsync(
            sql: "[dbo].[MetaTokens_Update]",
            param: parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            transaction: Transaction);
    }
```

```cs
    public async Task TestUpdateMetaTokenAsync()
    {

        // Arrange
        using var dbFixture = new DatabaseFixture();
        var factoryMock = new Mock<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        factoryMock
            .Setup(factory => factory.GetConnection())
            .Returns(() => dbFixture.Connection);
        var procedures = new MetaTokensProcedures(factoryMock.Object);

        // Arrange
        var expected = new MetaTokenRow()
        {
            Id = 3,
            IsRevoked = true
        };

        // Act
        await procedures.UpdateMetaTokenAsync(expected);
        procedures.Commit();
        var actual = await procedures.SelectMetaTokenByIdAsync(expected.Id);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected.Id, actual.Id);
        Assert.Equal(expected.IsRevoked, actual.IsRevoked);

    }
```

```cs
public class MetaTokenRow
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int TokenTypeKey { get; set; }

    public int PrincipalTypeKey { get; set; }

    public bool IsRevoked { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public void CopyTo(MetaTokenRow row)
    {
        row.Id = Id;
        row.TokenTypeKey = TokenTypeKey;
        row.PrincipalTypeKey = PrincipalTypeKey;
        row.IsRevoked = IsRevoked;
        row.CreatedAt = CreatedAt;
    }
}
```

In the previous code, I create my `expected` variable which contains information about the record I have previously inserted before running the test (Yes I double checked it, it is there). Next up, I pass the `MetaTokenRow` to the `UpdateMetaTokenAsync` method, which in turn uses it to setup the `DynamicParameters` for Dapper.
However, when running the test I get and Assert failure for the `IsRevoked` property, stating the expected value was `true`, but actual value was `false`. Hence the query didn't work I guess?

I tried running the stored procedure directly using SQL, and it works like a charm.
I tried changing the logic and having a `BIT` column record with value 1, update to value 0, meaning the expected value is `false`, and the test passes, but I am unsure of what does that mean.

In case it is required, here it is the query of how I am inserting the record before running the test.

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MetaTokens] ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MetaTokens] (
    [Id],  
    [TokenTypeKey],  
    [PrincipalTypeKey],  
    [IsRevoked], 
    [CreatedAt]) 
VALUES 
(3, 1, 1, 0, '2023-03-07 16:01:06 -06:00'); 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MetaTokens] OFF;
```

And here is the code for select the record which I just noticed is also relevant. Also, let me mention the "select" part of the operation hasn't giving me problems elsewhere.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MetaTokens_SelectById]
    @Id BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    
    SELECT 
        [Id], 
        [TokenTypeKey], 
        [PrincipalTypeKey], 
        [IsRevoked], 
        [CreatedAt]
    FROM [dbo].[MetaTokens]
    WHERE [Id] = @Id;

END
```

```cs
    public async Task<MetaTokenRow> SelectMetaTokenByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@Id", id);
        return await Connection.QuerySingleAsync<MetaTokenRow>(
            sql: "dbo.MetaTokens_SelectById",
            param: parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            transaction: Transaction);
    }
```

Comment: `inserted.CopyTo(row);` seems wrong, you are not actually getting any rows returned. Also, why `SELECT` then `UPDATE` when you can do it all in one statement `UPDATE ... SET IsRevoked = ISNULL(@IsRevoked, IsRevoked)...`

Comment: @Charlieface Apologies, I updated the code as I explained in another answer below. Regarding having a SELECT first and a UPDATE separately, it is just following a pattern used by other stored procedures in which we have more update-able columns and not all of them are always specified to be updated in the same call.

Comment: I'm no fan of stored procedures, so I don't use them myself, but it looks to me like you have a parameter @IsRevoked, and then you select into that same parameter overriding the value that was already there, before writing it to the table. Did I misunderstand anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY solved it.
I was setting the `@Id` parameter with a wrong value.

Previously it was:

```cs
    public async Task UpdateMetaTokenAsync(MetaTokenRow row)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@Id", row.TokenTypeKey);
        parameters.Add("@IsRevoked", row.IsRevoked);
        await Connection.ExecuteAsync(
            sql: "[dbo].[MetaTokens_Update]",
            param: parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            transaction: Transaction);
    }
```

But it should have been:

```cs
    public async Task UpdateMetaTokenAsync(MetaTokenRow row)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@Id", row.Id);
        parameters.Add("@IsRevoked", row.IsRevoked);
        await Connection.ExecuteAsync(
            sql: "[dbo].[MetaTokens_Update]",
            param: parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            transaction: Transaction);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query is asking the DBMS to return some data. You want to update, hence you should use ExecuteAsync:

```cs
public async Task UpdateMetaTokenAsync(MetaTokenRow row)
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@Id", row.TokenTypeKey);
    parameters.Add("@IsRevoked", row.IsRevoked);
    var inserted = await Connection.ExecuteAsync<MetaTokenRow>(
        sql: "[dbo].[MetaTokens_Update]",
        param: parameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        transaction: Transaction);
    inserted.CopyTo(row);
}
```

It will return the number of affected rows.

Comment: My apologies, I was trying other things to debug the code before posting here. I updated it by, using ExecuteAsync in the update and including the CopyTo method which is still relevant for the Select method. I still get the same error